# Como actualizar registros en null a un id autoincrementable a tabla existente con datos

Tags: firebird

tengo una tabla con datos en Firebird, necesito crear un campo para tener un id unico para cada registro, ya agregue el campo que se llamara ID, ahora como actualizo los registros existentes para que tengan un ID unico y autoincrementable para nuevos registros, ya que todos estan en null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que realizar dos pasos,

1. Aplicar el auto-increment a la columna para esto tienes dos opciones:

a) Crear un generador, por ejemplo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

b) Usar IDENTITY COLUMNS como campos para auto-incremento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda crear el GENERATOR apartir de los registros que ya tienes, por ejemplo, si ya tienes 15 registros el generator lo creas apartir de 15.

2. Una vez ya hayas modificado la columna apropiadamente, tienes que incrementar el ID de cada registro, esto lo haces con transacciones, como no se que lenguaje estas utilizando ni tu base de datos te dejare algunos ejemplos:

   var estimatesRef = firebase.child('Estimates');
   estimatesRef.once('value', function(estimatesSnapshot) {
     estimatesSnapshot.forEach(function(estimateSnapshot) {
       estimateSnapshot.ref().update({
         estimateSnapshot.val().priority + 1
       });
     });
   });

El anterior codigo, itera dentro de todos los hijos de estimados y los incrementa.

```
public void incrementCounter() {
    firebase.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
            if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
                currentData.setValue(1);
            } else {
                currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
            }

            return Transaction.success(currentData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
            if (firebaseError != null) {
                Log.d("Firebase counter increment failed.");
            } else {
                Log.d("Firebase counter increment succeeded.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

El anterior codigo es en Java.

Te dejo algunas referencias

[Manual FireBird seccion PrimaryTables](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fbdevgd-en/Firebird_Devel_Guide_30EN.pdf)
[Manual FireBird realizar transaccion en diferentes lenguajes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)

Comment: Me apoyarias con scritp sql de trasnaccion para firebird IBexpert por favor

Comment: Manejo IBExpert para adiminstrar mis BD, pero no he podido realizar el paso 2 en sql de mi gestor